# LINUX:how to find time+ in top?

Tags: ubuntu

i m implementing my own top command .i just cant find out where to find SHR(shared memory),TIME+(process start time) and mem% of each process from proc.
please reply :)

Comment: The `/proc` file system has a sub directory for each process running named for its PID number.  Look at the data available to you in there.  perhaps `status`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, got it SHM will be `/proc/$pid/statm` field number 3 multiplied by 4.
Because page size is 4096 and SHM is measured in kilobytes.

The TIME+ is `cat /proc/$pid/stat | awk '{ print ($14+$15)/100 }'`
Summ of the field 14 and 15 devided by 100 (because clock tick is 100Hz).

Byt why are you making your own top, and i think there can be process related libraries to get the data you need.

Comment: Thank you very much sir....it's an assignment given to me...more over I would like to know us% sy%  ni% id% wa% si% hi%

Comment: What language are you using? Maybe there is a library ready for you? Like this one https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/